# Getting a NullPointerException on seemingly good code?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm having an issue where I have a player object that I'm trying to send to a method, and it doesn't work. As far as I can tell, however, it should. Any ideas?

The line on which I find the error:

```
keybl.playerUpdate(player);
```

Wherein "keybl" is a KeyListener that is initialized and is functioning in code before this runs, "playerUpdate" is a method seen below, and "player" is a Player object which is, in fact, initialized properly.

```
public void playerUpdate(Player somePlayer) {

    user = somePlayer;

}
```

Wherein "user" is a class variable of type "Player" that is set to a different player object when this is run.

Any ideas?

Comment: It must be that `keybl` is null if that's where the exception is thrown. Have you debugged this?

Comment: Can you paste stack trace of your exception along with the question? Otherwise the question is very ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the exception is on this line:

```
keybl.playerUpdate(player);
```

then it must be that `keybl` is null. Add one `System.out.println("keybl: " + keybl);` before this line and you should see it printing `null` at some point (or to be precise - before the exception is thrown).

Comment: Thank you. I feel somewhat stupid. I had commented out its initialization before to test something, but this prompted me to go back and re-check. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: No problem, hey - it happens!